# consider somebody/something + adj. | consider somebody/something (to be) something

Tags: meaning, sentence-construction

Is there a difference between these two forms ?

> 1- A dog is considered ***old*** if it lives seven years.
>
> 2- A dog is considered ***to be old*** if it lives seven years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### There is no difference in meaning, the choice is a matter of style

This question was discussed on the [English Language and Usage Exchange](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/57082/328839) and has some good answers if you're curious to read more on the topic of when/why it is acceptable to drop "to be" in some cases.